# How to achieve a "vertical reveal" effect on iOS, preferably with a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, user-interface

I'm trying to achieve an effect similar to what can be seen in [this video](https://adshowcase.verizonmedia.com/detail/493/?region=1).

Note that I'm talking about the "vertical reveal" effect, not the "horizontal carousel" effect.

Ideally, it should work with a UITableView, but I'm aware that it could not be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

TableViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

TableViewController.m

```
#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"

#define ROW 7
#define ROW_HEIGHT 100

@interface TableViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) CustomCell *customCell;

@end

@implementation TableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"IDENTIFIER1"];

    self.customCell = [[CustomCell alloc] init];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 20;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == ROW) {
        return self.customCell;
    }

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"IDENTIFIER1" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == ROW) {
        return self.tableView.frame.size.height;
    }

    return ROW_HEIGHT;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    CGFloat top = ROW * ROW_HEIGHT;

    if (offsetY >= top - scrollView.frame.size.height) {
        self.customCell.mainView.frame = CGRectMake(0, offsetY - top, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height);
    }
}

@end
```

CustomCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) WKWebView *mainView;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

CustomCell.m

```
#import "CustomCell.h"

@implementation CustomCell

- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor; // XXX

        WKWebViewConfiguration *configuration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
        self.mainView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero configuration:configuration];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test1.htm"]];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [self.mainView loadRequest:request];

        self.mainView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
        self.mainView.scrollView.bouncesZoom = NO;

        [self.contentView addSubview:self.mainView];
        self.contentView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

test1.htm

```
<html>
    <head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"></head>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 24px;
            background-color: #ffff00;
            background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAEAAAABACAYAAACqaXHeAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAAAlwSFlzAAALEgAACxIB0t1+/AAAABx0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAQWRvYmUgRmlyZXdvcmtzIENTNui8sowAAAAWdEVYdENyZWF0aW9uIFRpbWUAMTAvMjkvMTm1eHLxAAAAm0lEQVR4nO3QQRHAMAzAsGT8OWcw9KiFwOedmbu7nUd9OkBrgA7QGqADtAboAK0BOkBrgA7QGqADtAboAK0BOkBrgA7QGqADtAboAK0BOkBrgA7QGqADtAboAK0BOkBrgA7QGqADtAboAK0BOkBrgA7QGqADtAboAK0BOkBrgA7QGqADtAboAK0BOkBrgA7QGqADtOcH7MycjpB+hI8Fez5BjwUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=");
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 160px;
            color: #ff0000;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        function loop(timestamp) {
            var element = document.getElementById("main");
            element.innerText = timestamp;

            window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
        }

        window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    </script>

    <body>
        <div id="main"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this behaviour by creating footer view that have height of tableView's parent.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var footer: UIView!
    var tableView: UITableView!
    let cellId = "CellID"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let redView = UIView()
        redView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        redView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
        redView.center = self.view.center
        redView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleTopMargin, .flexibleRightMargin, .flexibleBottomMargin]
        self.view.addSubview(redView)

        let footer = UIView()
        footer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(sender:)))
        footer.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
        self.footer = footer

        let tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        tableView.frame = self.view.bounds
        tableView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
        self.tableView = tableView
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
        cell.backgroundColor = .green
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 200
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return self.footer
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return self.view.bounds.height
    }

    @objc func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        self.tableView.frame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.height
        self.tableView.contentOffset = .zero
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
            self.tableView.frame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.origin.y
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mark, your answer was helpful. It indeed works for the first part of the effect, but not for the second part (when the cells that come below the ad are scrolled-in from the bottom)

Comment: @ArielMalka I'm add modification in the answer.
The main idea i's that we set content offset to zero, hide table view by moving it to the bottom of viewController view and show it with animation be return to viewController view origin y.
The trigger of that animation is tap gesture on the tableViewFooterView.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I'm looking for a solution where the cells coming from the bottom are numbered 5, 6, 7, etc. and with regular dragging of the table content (i.e. no triggered animation.)
I made something actually. Will share when its finalized...

Comment: You can place tableview on top of the background view. When the back view is supposed to be shown, add a tableviewcell with clear background and height equal to tableview at that index. Also keep clear background of tableview. In this way tableview will keep scrolling and new cells will appear from bottom.